# Sending Image through intent after CameraAPI opens

Tags: java, android, memory, camera

I am trying to build a function for the android phone that will open the CameraAPI and then send the captured picture to a new activity.

In this activity i need it to show a preview for the image and then save.

How could i go about doing this without having to save the image to the SD card?

Comment: Why don't you want to save it to the SD card? The simplest way to acquire a photo is to use startActivityForResult() and ask the camera app to do the work for you, but that will save the image to a file.

Comment: The idea is security, if it saves it locally the image can be grabbed...as well as saved and viewed from the gallery. My application if put in the wrong hands that could be bad for the person using it. As well could be used by the government in top security if needed.

Comment: Check out this answer then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963581/how-to-capture-an-android-camera-image-without-saving-a-file-to-the-phone-sdcard

Answer (score 0):

You can store the image into a bitmap and then convert it to byte array and then transfer to other activity through this code below

```
 Bitmap bitmapPicture= "PICTURE FROM CAMERA";
 ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
```

Then Pass Through Intent

```
 Intent imagepass = new Intent(Cam.this,Preview.class);
 imagepass.putExtra("imagepass", bytes.toByteArray());
 startActivity(imagepass);
```

In Other Activity we have to recieve the byte array and convert to bitmap and display in imageview through

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("imagepass");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

    ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvw2);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

You will have to use custom camera control Hope This Helps.